# 'a bit of' vs. 'a lot of'

Tags: word-choice

I am confused about these two sentences:

> 1. That's a **bit** of a difficult answer to give in a few words.
> 2. That's a **lot** of a difficult answer to give in a few words.

Which sentence is the correct one?

Answer (score 2):

*A bit.*

I've just never seen *a lot* used like this--it would mean something a bit strange.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both *a bit of a* and *a lot of a* if you mean *a small part of* and *a large part* of something:

> She ate a bit of a cookie.
>
> She ate a lot of a cookie.

However, *a bit of a* can also mean *quite a*, or *rather a*, as in the following.

> We are in a bit of a mess. = We are in quite a mess.
>
> That is a bit of a difficult answer. = That is quite a difficult
>   answer.

Unfortunately, we cannot use *a lot of a* in a similar way to mean *very*:

> *We are in a lot of a mess.
>
> *That is a lot of a difficult answer.

It has to be something like:

> We are in a big mess.
>
> That is a very difficult answer.

Answer (score 0):

First one indicates that the answer is slightly difficult to express in few words. Second one implies that the answer is too tough to express in few words. Both imply different meaning.However,in general first one is most common to use in our daily life.

Comment: Yes second one seems inappropriate to use